# ModernCV place quote right under the address

Tags: moderncv

[image]

Hi I would like to move the quote above so that it is aligned with the info given above and not starts as a separate paragraph. How do I do that? I use `moderncv` `banking` style.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans, dvipsnames]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}                          
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}


\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-90){\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{images/CV_image.jpg}}
\end{picture}

\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\hfil}
  {\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
 
\name{Filip}{xxx}
\title{CV}                               
\address{ xxxxxxx 00, 0000 xxxxx  }{}{}
\quote{\small A data scientist with dedication for research and passion for its applications. }
\phone[mobile]{+41 1234567}                   
\email{xxx@gmail.com}                               

\begin{document}
\makecvhead
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to patch `\makehead` to add there the quote like this:

```
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}}
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}
   \flushmakeheaddetails\par\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}{}%
    {{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  }
  {}
  {}
```

Now we have to delete the quote from command `\makecvhead` like this:

```
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{% TODO: use \@initializecommand, which requires modifying its definition to handle \par
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \makehead%
  }
```

With the following MWE you will get the wished result:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans, dvipsnames]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking} % head 3 body 3
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}

\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\hfil}
  {\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}}
  {}
  {}
  
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\makehead}
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}}
  {\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}
   \flushmakeheaddetails\par\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}{}%
    {{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  }
  {}
  {}

\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{% TODO: use \@initializecommand, which requires modifying its definition to handle \par
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  \makehead%
  }
\makeatother % <========================================================
 
\name{Filip}{xxx}
\title{CV}                               
\address{ xxxxxxx 00, 0000 xxxxx  }{}{}
\quote{\small A data scientist with dedication for research and passion for its applications. }
\phone[mobile]{+41 1234567}                   
\email{xxx@gmail.com}                               


\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-90){\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{example-image}}
\end{picture}

\makecvhead
\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]